# Can I use testrail ui scripts in a specific project only?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, testrail

I have multiple projects in testrail, I want to be able to apply a ui script just for one of those projects, for example post to slack.

Testrail include and exclude only take URL parameters which does not have the project id to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myProject = document.getElementById("navigation-project").innerHTML
    if(myProject =="PROJECT NAME") {
        //alert('myProject')
        //Your Code Here
    }
```

[TestRail-ProjectName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UJXC.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).